# Need Example of JGit to push code files to git server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jgit, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I am trying to push the selenium scripts to git server so that jenkins will automatically download the latest scripts. I wanted to give web interface to select the automation scripts and upload the same scripts in Git. I want to programatically handle the pushing of choosen files to server so that only those files are run for automation. I need an example from JGit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the [`PushCommand`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.9.0.201710071750-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommand.html) for invoking a push to a remote server. There are options among others for choosing which `remote` is pushed to.

Keep in mind that you cannot push some files selectively, but only whole commits on a branch, so there is no way to do what you would like with simple push. An option would be to create separate commits on a separate branch and only push this one branch via defining the references via the [`PushCommand.add()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.9.0.201710071750-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommand.html#add-java.lang.String-) method.

```
try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
    git.push().call();
}
```

See also a related [snippet in the jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/unfinished/PushToRemoteRepository.java#L73)

Comment: You might want to check the `PushResult`s returned by the push-command, too.